# How to use Jsoup to find element by ID?

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape the Top Stories section in google news for all the titles. In order to only get the titles in the Top Stories section, I must narrow into this tag:

```
<div class="section top-stories-section" id=":2r">..</div>
```

This is the code I use (in Eclipse):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // fetches & parses HTML        
    String url = "http://news.google.com";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 

    // Extract data

    Element topStories = document.getElementById(":2r").;
    Elements titles = topStories.select("span.titletext");



    // Output data
    for (Element title : titles) {
        System.out.println("Title: " + title.text());
    }
}
```

I always seem to be getting a NullPointerException. It doesn't work either, when I try to reach the Top Stories like this:

```
Element topStories = document.select("#:2r").first();
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't this be working? I am relatively new to this, please help and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the error message (and actually looking at the page) that `div` tag doesn't contain an `id` attribute. Instead you could select based on the CSS class

```
Element topStories = document.select("div.section.top-stories-section").first();
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. Two questions, though: How does that div tag not contain an id attribute (it clearly says 'id=":2r"')? Why does that work if the full class name is "section top-stories-section" and not just "top-stories-section"? I am new to this, so I am interested in learning. Thanks a ton, though!

Comment: As stated the original error indicates that it can't find `:2r` the element so not sure where u got that originally. 2) will work with either css class only. Have updated to show 2 classes together - more correct :)